# Invoking Angular Component with HTML Link (using Bootstrap?) from any page in Angular Application

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, activation

How can you activate an Angular 4+ component an HTML link NOT associated with the component like a templateURL INSIDE the component. I'm asking for an OUTSIDE the box activation. Now, I've tried to get this bootstrap idea to work:

```
<a data-target="#ngComponent">SOME USER HELP</a>
```

and

```
<a target="#ngComponent">SOME USER HELP</a>
```

I've seen bootstrap modals activated this way (I'm actually using a modal in this use case too). But, I couldn't get it to work, any ideas why? Also, it's VERY important in my use case NOT to route to another page upon activation, which makes it even more difficult. So, something like this below:

```
<div routerLink="ngComponent">SOME USER HELP</div>
```

Will not work for my use case, unless you know of a way to do it without changing the user's current page. Finally, this component need to be accessed from any HTML page's LINK anywhere in the application. Hope I've been clear and concise in my description of the problem I'm faced with.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Thanks user184994 for formatting help :)

Comment: May be using ngx-bootstrap modals will help you achieve your goal, please check demos here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Answer (score 0):

can you do something like

```
<div class="componentStying">
    <ngComponent></ngComponent>
</div>
```

That is how I am referencing different components in my project. Any `@Input() myInput` and `@Output() myOutput` are referenced like so

```
<ngComponent [myInput]="'hello, world'" (myOutput)="myVar"></ngComponent>
```